# Target only the contents of a folder in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using Gulp to compile a project. I'm also using [gulp-zip](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-zip) to zip a bunch of files.

I want to zip up all the files in the "dist" folder, so I'm using this:

```
var thesrc: ['dist/**/*'];
gulp.task('createMainZip', ['createPluginZip'], function () {
    return gulp.src(thesrc)
    .pipe(zip('main_files.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('compiled'));
});
```

This compiles the files to a zip in the following way:

- dist

  - file.css
  - another.js
  - folder

    - file.js

However, I want it like this:

- file.css
- another.js
- folder

  - file.js

Without the dist folder. Is there a way to do this using a different src path?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gulp-zip doesn't honor `base`. See for some background:

- https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-zip/issues/10
- https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-zip/pull/11
- https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-zip/blob/master/index.js#L30

Now, you can do something like that (admittedly ugly):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var zip = require('gulp-zip');
var thesrc = ['**/*'];
gulp.task('createMainZip', function () {
  return gulp.src(thesrc, {cwd: __dirname + "/dist"})
  .pipe(zip('main_files.zip'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('compiled'));
});
```

Comment: Ugly, but it works! Hopefully gulp-zip will be updated in future to honor base.

Comment: how to make it work if executing file is not in root of project?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try:

```
return gulp.src(thesrc, {base: 'dist'})
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. It still zips the 'dist' folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me, following *did* work:

```js
// Taking everything from src and doc dirs
return gulp.src(['src/**/*', 'doc/**/*'], { base: __dirname })
  .pipe(zip('dist.zip'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

Comment: Perhaps this works because `__dirname` is the current file's directory which is at the same level as the `src` directory? This doesn't work for me when I use something other than `__dirname`.