# GulpJS copy folders and files from folder "foo" to folder "bar" and retain folder structure

Tags: gulp

I've got a folder "foo" and folder "bar", and I want to copy and run specific tasks on a specific files files.

Problem: I can copy files, run tasks on them and retain folder structure, but when I move files to folder "bar" it creates a folder "foo" inside folder "bar" and stores all copied files inside it.

Tried: Tried to change `base: '.'` to `base: '../'` but that just makes it compile everything to parent folder of `bar`.

Folder structure:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── models
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── images
│   │   └── js
│   ├── routes
│   └── scss
├── bar
│   └── ...
└── gulpfile.js
```

Gulpjs.js File:

```
var gulp     = require('gulp');
var uglify   = require('gulp-uglify');
var sass     = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var cssmin   = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename   = require('gulp-rename');
var htmlmin  = require('gulp-htmlmin');

var paths = {
    'ssjs' : ['foo/app.js', 'foo/routes/*.js', 'foo/models/*.js'],
    'csjs' : ['foo/public/js/*.js'],
    'sass' : ['foo/scss/*.scss', 'foo/scss/modules/*.scss'],
    'html' : ['foo/public/*.html'],
    'build' : 'bar',
    'public': 'public'
};

gulp.task('ssjs', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.ssjs, {'base': '.'})
            .pipe(uglify({'preserveComments': 'some'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build));
});

gulp.task('csjs', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.csjs, {'base': '.'})
            .pipe(uglify({'preserveComments': 'some'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.sass, {'base': '.'})
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(cssmin())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.html, {'base': '.'})
            .pipe(htmlmin({'collapseWhitespace': true}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.ssjs, ['ssjs']);
    gulp.watch(paths.csjs, ['csjs']);
    gulp.watch(paths.scss, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', [ 'ssjs', 'csjs', 'sass', 'html', 'watch' ]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Target only the contents of a folder in gulp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606192/target-only-the-contents-of-a-folder-in-gulp)

Comment: Sweet, that worked. Changed `'base': '.'` to `'base': 'foo'`.

Comment: I wish I got points for at least helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: change `'base': '.'` to `'base': 'foo'`